# Showing that this set is a subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given that $a$ is any vector in a vector space $V$, show that the set $\{xa : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ of all scalar multiples of $a$ is a subspace of $V$.

In order for the set $\{xa : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ to be a subspace of $V$, by showing that it is closed under multiplication and addition.

Well this seems like a trivial question because clearly when $a$ is multiplied by any scalar value $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $a$ will still be in $V$. Likewise for addition, since we know $a \in V$ and we know $\{xa : x \in \mathbb{R}\} \in V$, then it is clear that we have closure of addition too.

I would like to know if my explanation is sufficient enough and also clear enough to others to answer the above question, thanks

Comment: You should specify the field over which $V$ is assumed to be a vector space. Regarding your proof, the addition part isn't very clear. Also don't forget (although it's quite easy) to show that the proposed subspace is nonempty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) clearly the set is non empty

2) let $xa,ya$ be in the set, then $xa+ya=(x+y)a$. Since the addition of two real numbers is a real number, $(x+y)a$ is in the set.

3) let A be any real scalar. Let $xa$ be arbitrary, then $A(xa)$ $=$ $(Ax)a$ since the product of two real numbers is likewise real, $(Ax)a$ is in the set. Therefore the set is a subspace of the vector space V.

Comment: thanks. 2) was very helpful to see how clearly closure of addition can be stated

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think it is sufficient to exhibit the closedness under scalar multiplication and addition.

But your addition part is not exactly right. Let $W=\{xa:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. It should be like $xa\in W,\ ya\in W\implies xa+ya=(x+y)a\in W$.

In principle, you have to show the axioms for a vector space hold, but if you are verifying whether a subset becomes a substructure then only certain closednesses need to be verified, because other properties naturally hold.

Also, be careful if you are doing similar things with other structures, where you may have to verify closedness under inverse too.

Comment: Shouldn't you start with elements in the set $\{xa: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, rather than $V$? The implication you have written is true by default since $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out. I have edited the answer